# OSM2PGSQL - Openstreetmap Tiles showing no detail at certain levels

Tags: postgis, leaflet, openstreetmap, postgis-2.0, mapnik

I recently built myself a Map server using this guide:

https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/openstreetmap-tile-server-ubuntu-16-04

This has worked really well to an extent.

I have however noticed peculiarities at certain zoom levels.

At this level I can see everything perfectly:
[image: Detailed Map]

However if I zoom out further I lose all detail and am basically left with land outlines:
[image: Map]

Is this perhaps a caching or stylesheet issue?

I'm using the carto stylesheet as suggested in the tutorial. Also if it were caching I'd expect to just see blank tiles rather than outlines. Curiously if I'm zoomed in further and the tiles haven't cached they show as blank before rendering normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's probably happened is that you've previously tested the procedure with a smaller dataset, and have some mostly blank tiles left over from that.  You can either delete all your cached tiles (probably /var/lib/mod_tile/STYLE/? and /var/lib/mod_tile/STYLE/?? , where "STYLE" is the style defined in your renderd.conf file) or force rerender them, either manually by viewing an individual tile URL and appending "/dirty" to the end or by using something like "render_list" (part of mod_tile) to force-rerender a range of tiles.

Comment: That is correct. I have deleted the cached tiles and run the following command:

render_list -m default -a -z 0 -Z 10

Which has forced renderd to re-render the tiles.

Comment: Just to add another option - https://github.com/alx77/render_list_geo.pl allows the rendering of tiles in a particular geographic area.